# How to open https in iframe from http page?

Tags: iframe, https

I have main page which opens via http. On this page I open iframe with same domain but via https and get error message:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the main page (http) could access the iframe (https) it will be a security problem!

More informations this security feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Just move the main page to https, it will solve your problem and secure your visitors.